# Change background colour of view programatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to change the background colour of my `View` programatically, using a colour that I defined in my resources. Other SO posts explain to do it like this:

```
int color = ContextCompat.GetColor(this.context, Resource.Color.my_color_background);
this.myView.SetBackgroundColor(color);
```

But this doesn't work for me, because `SetBackgroundColor` takes a `Color`, not an int... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this event Android syntax that you use.

Comment: I am using Xamarin, so C#, but I don't think it makes a difference?

Comment: How come [`setBackgroundColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)) takes `Color` not `int`?

Comment: That's what I want to know...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just creating the `Color` object myself and setting it with that:

```
int color = ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.my_color);
this.view.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(color));
```

Not sure why the constructor is different in Xamarin though...